# How to generate 256 bits AES key

Tags: java, encryption, aes

For generating AES key of 256 bits, i wrote following code:

```
KeyGenerator keyGen;

try {
  keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
  keyGen.init(256);
  SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
  return secretKey;    
}
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  return null;
}
```

My encryption method is:

```
  private byte[] aes256Encode(SecretKey key, IvParameterSpec iv, String message) throws InvalidKeyException,
      InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
      NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
      IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException 
  {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
    return encrypted;
  }
```

and IV generation method is:

```
  private IvParameterSpec generateAESIV() {
    // build the initialization vector (randomly).
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte iv[] = new byte[16];//generate random 16 byte long
    random.nextBytes(iv);
    IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    return ivspec;
  }
```

But while encryption, it is throwing following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1039)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:805)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:864)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1396)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1327)
```

Can anyone point out the mistake i am making here?

Comment: Next time you search for the exception message, before you post a duplicate question, ok?

Comment: Thanks @Tom for the suggestion. It worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you update the JCE jars?.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

Java gets shipped with a default 128bit. Take a look and let me know

Comment: Thanks @Aravind R ..it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

`keyGen.init(256);`

To

`keyGen.init(128);`

By default, Java supports only 128-bit encryption.

**Edit:**
If you need to encrypt content with keys larger than 128 bit, you have to use [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html).